# Mongoose está atualizando objeto errado no mongodb

Tags: node.js, ionic, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Estou com um problema ao salvar os dados no mongodb.

**Contexto**

Tenho uma api em express que escuta requisições para salvar os dados no mongodb que um aplicativo envia. Esses dados são relativos as visualizações de páginas do APP, cliques, etc.

**add.js**

Este é o arquivo responsável por atualizar o campo `dataEvent: {type: Array, require: true}` no model do mongoose. Nesta rota eu procuro pelo id que é enviado pelo aplicativo e faço um push nessa Array.

```
require('../models/Event')

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Event = mongoose.model("event")
const { validateToken } = require('../helpers/validateToken')
const {Console} = require('../providers/console-provider')
const {response} = require('../helpers/response-helper')


router.put('/', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.body.id
    data = req.body.body
    console.log(data)
    if(id != undefined & data != undefined){
    Event.findOne({_id: id}).then(async (doc)=>{
        await doc.dataEvent.push(data)
        doc.save().then(async (s)=>{
            console.log("Add com  sucesso")
            console.log(s)
            await response(200, "Evento adicionado com sucesso!", res)
        }).catch(()=>{
            res.status(500)
            res.send({error: true, info: "Não foi possível adicionar o     evento!"})
        })


    }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500)
            res.send({error: true, info: "Não foi possível adicionar o         evento!"})

    })
}else{
    console.log("Dados da requisição inválidos!")
    res.status(500)
    res.send({error: true, info: "Dados inválidos"})
}
})

module.exports = router
```

**Console**

No console é exibido esse resultado (tem alguns dados confidenciais, mas o dataEvent é exibido, com os dois registros):

```
Add com  sucesso
{ dataEvent:
   [ { type: 'view', page: 'login-page' },
     { type: 'click', page: 'doctor-list' } ],
  _id: 5dc030cba1752e1b08847884
```

**O problema**

O problema em tudo isso é que no mongodb o registro que é feito o push, não é salvo! Ele deveria ter o registro adicionado na rota do arquivo `add.js`

[image: Usando o Robo 3T]

**server.js**

Este é o arquivo do servidor

```
require('dotenv/config')

const {
    express,
    http,
    providers: {
        consoleProvider: {
            Console
        }
    },
    routes: {
        init,
        update,
        add
    },
    mongoose,
    bodyParser,
    cors,
    verifyToken: {
        validateToken
    }
} = require('./import')

const app = express()
const c = Console

if (process.env.ENV == "PROD") {
    bd_host = process.env.BD_PROD
} else if (process.env.ENV == "TEST") {
    bd_host = process.env.BD_TEST
} else {
    bd_host = process.env.BD_DEV
}
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

mongoose.connect(bd_host, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true             }
    .then((success) => { Console("Banco de dados conectado!") })
    .catch((error) => { Console("Erro ao se conectar com a base de dados!")     })

app.use('/init', validateToken, init)
app.use('/add', validateToken, add)
app.use('/update', validateToken, update)

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500)
    res.json({ error: true, info: "Erro interno no servidor" })
})

app.listen(
    process.env.PORT,
    () => {
        Console("Servidor rodando na porta: " + process.env.PORT)
    }
)
```

**Situação encontrada**

Quando o aplicativo manda uma solicitação para a rota `/init` ele gera um id onde é armazenado no dispositivo. Porém quando é feita a requisição na rota `/add` Ele atualiza um id anterior. Vou mostrar na foto: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se vc tem algum arquivo de configuração do servidor, mas uma das coisas que pode estar acontencendo é o express não entender o req.body, caso vc não tenha colocadoem outro lugar, adicinona isso abaixo do require do express;

```
const express = require('express')
express.use(express.json())
const router = express.Router()
```

e verifica se o req.body está trazendo os dados do front.

tenta mudar o doc.save() para doc.update();

Comment: Eu estou passando isso no server.js. que é o arquivo do servidor que está escutando a porta. Os dados vem tudo certinho, pois o mongoose adiciona o registro que vem do aplicativo. Porém no banco de dados ele não salva!

Comment: Fala Eduardo uma curiosidade, vc está fazendo o require('../models/Event') e depois const Event = mongoose.model('event'), porque na sua model vc ja não retorna um new mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema)? vc correria menos riscos errar o nome da model

Comment: Eu tenho um model que chamo o mongoose e o Schema, dai faço o new Event nesse model e chamo o mongoose.model('event',EventSchema)

Comment: Entendi, tenta mudar o doc.save() para doc.update() visto que vc só quer atualizar o schema e não criar outro.

Comment: hmmmm, ok vou tentar

Comment: Aconteceu a mesma coisa, ao invés de ele adicionar na array dataEvent do objeto criado pela rota /init ele adicionou no objeto anterior.

Comment: O Fabio, tipo depois de criar o registro no mongo eu tenho que atualizar o modelo no mongoose, ou ele faz isso sozinho?

Comment: Como assim atualizar o modelo no mongoose? o que vc precisa fazer é enviar o id do registro que vc quer atualizar, provavelmente no Event.findOne({_id: id}) provavelmete o id passado está errado

Comment: O id que vem da API é o mesmo que é gerado pela rota /init. Não sei porque motivo ele está pegando o anterior

Comment: Bom, talvez seja melhor vc abrir outra pergunta passando o cenário atual, acho que assim ficaria mais fácil da galera ajudar visto que o problema agora é outro kkkk.

Comment: Vou atualizar o título dessa aqui

Comment: Blz Eduardo, espero ter ajudado man, abraço